# python request 404 after istio injected

Tags: kubernetes, istio, rancher

I set up istio from rancher catalog app,

after set namespace with istio enabled and redeploy workload,

requests google inside container get 404 error.

here is code example inside container with python3.

```
In [1]: import requests

In [2]: requests.get('http://google.com')

Out[2]:<Response [404]>
```

what is the best practice of requesting outside host with istio injected?

Answer (score 3):

Quote from [istio document](https://istio.io/docs/examples/advanced-egress/egress-gateway/):

> A quick reminder: by default, Istio-enabled applications are unable to
>   access URLs outside the cluster. To enable such access, a service
>   entry for the external service must be defined, or, alternatively,
>   direct access to external services must be configured.

Answer (score 0):

Add a service entry and virtual service for google.com using [this](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/#configuring-the-external-services) documentation